# Show number of marker in Google map in an area, according to zoom level of the map in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using GMap for my iOS application.

I have already added a set of markers according to our data.

But when the map get zoom out the markers are overlapping each other, this seems not good.

What my need is to show the count or the number of markers according to the map zoom level. Means if  2 markers are overlapping each other,then show a single label with text 2 as marker, so on...

Comment: you can get count from the marker object if its a list or array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you search is `marker clustering`

see this documentation from [Google Maps iOS SDK: Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)

it uses the ios utils:
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils

Answer (score 1):

Google maps do not provide such API or delegate function to do your thing, but what you can do is that every time map is zoomed out you can get the current Zoom level and replace the previous markers with a single customised [2 places] marker.

// To replace the marker

You can create a custom marker class "MyMarker.class" inheriting from GMSMarker class, now if you want to provide index of data from array to the marker then add a variable markerID in "MyMarker.class". Assign array index of data to markerID, and change the particular marker based on zoom level.

To find the visible area

```
func snapToMarkerIfItIsOutsideViewport(m: GMSMarker) {

    let region: GMSVisibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
    let bounds: GMSCoordinateBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(region: region)
    if !bounds.containsCoordinate(m.position) {
        // marker is outside the visible map, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i am old school about the clustering, i will update myself on that